# PrismaJs - подсказки не появляются, какой плагин установить для webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

### Webstorm, плагин для PrismaJs.

Пробую сеё чудо, но нашел только поддержку синтатксиса, есть ли подсказки? У преподавателя есть, но он на vs коде сидит. Благодарю!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14240-prisma - "Add support for the Prisma Schema Language (PSL)"

Comment: если это то, что нужно - оформи ответ и отметь его как принятый.

Comment: да, спасибо большое за помощь! Оформите пожалуйста ответ в виде ответа, сейчас вы написали в секции комментарии. И еще один вопрос если не сложно, как мне в vscode допустим, или webstorm. Допустим у меня есть элемент <Col md={2}></Col> есть ли способ сразу перейти к тому чтобы изменить значение 2? Я работаю на vim, пока что просто двигаюсь через w к нему, ужасно долго.